# Notation for smallest value greater than a number in a sorted set

Tags: real-analysis, notation, soft-question

In a finite set, is there a concept/notation for the smallest value larger than a particular element? For example, I have a sorted set as $ A = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_k \} $ where $  a_2 > a_1, a_3 > a_2, ... , a_{k} > a_{k-1},  $. Given an arbitrary value $p$ not be in the set, I want to find the smallest element $a_k$ in the set greater than $p$. Any idea?

Comment: Not following. Why isn't it just $a_{m+1}$?

Comment: Maybe the notation you're looking for is $\min\{a\in A:a>x\}$.

Comment: @lulu Edited the question

Comment: You use $a_m$ to denote the $m^{th}$ element in the set *and* also to denote some value which may or may not be in the set?  That is extremely poor notation.

Comment: The term "successor" might be appropriate. Its meaning should be defined in the context, of course.

Comment: There seems to be an unstated assumption about the "arbitrary value $p$ not ... in the set" $A$.  While $A$ is said to be finite and "sorted" (totally ordered), it isn't clear where $p$ comes from.  Presumably there is some larger set containing $p$ and including $A$, upon which some nice ordering is defined.  Even so, it is possible from what you wrote that *none* of the elements $a_k$ is greater than $p$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Karl mentioned in the comments, $\min\{a\in A:a>x\}$ might be what you want. Also, for finite sets, you can also use infimum (or $\inf$). However, $\inf$ only gives the minimum for finite sets and some infinite sets like $[0,1]$ - for other infinite sets, it is the greatest lower bound. See this Wikipedia page to learn more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: I was aware of infimum and supremum. However how can they be used with respect to a particular value, such as $p$ described in the question? I think they are absolute for a set, but you can explain in the answer if I am missing anything.

Comment: @ewr3243 Hello again. How about $\inf\{a\in A:a>x\}$?